# Pattern matching against value with generic type

Tags: generics, scala, pattern-matching

I'm writing tree-based expression evaluator, ans I've run into some troubles with type-erasure.

Tree looks like

```
sealed abstract class Node[+T]
case class Var[+T](name:String) extends Node[T]
/* SNIP */
```

The evaluator is

```
def eval[T](node:Node[T], context:Map[String, Any]):Option[T] = node match {
  case Var(name) => context.get(name) match {
    case Some(value:T) => Some(value)
    case _ => None
  }
  /* SNIP */
}
```

The code compiles, but type checks on `Var` nodes don't work. So this test fails:

```
class ContextEvaluatorTest extends FunSuite with ShouldMatchers {
  test("evaluation with type mismatch") {
    ContextEvaluator.eval(Var[Int]("a"), Map("a" -> "not int")) should equal (None)
  }
}
```

Error message is

```
org.scalatest.TestFailedException: Some(not int) did not equal None
```

Situation looks like a use-case for manifests, but I couldn't add them properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
def eval[T:ClassManifest](node:Node[T], context:Map[String, Any]):Option[T] = node match {
  case Var(name) => context.get(name) match {
    case Some(value:T) if classManifest[T].erasure.isInstance(value) => Some(value)
    case _ => None
  }
  case _ => None
}
```

Note however that `T` must be a simple type, AFAIK `ClassManifest` can't distinguish between things like `List[Int]` and `List[String]`. Probably `Manifest`can do that, but then the investigation is more complicated than calling `isInstance` on the underlying class.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `T` is *erased*. That means `value: T` in the pattern match is meaningless. In fact, the compiler should have warned you about that.

You'll have to resort to using manifests to make that test. See [Landei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/375232/landei)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038866/pattern-matching-against-value-with-generic-type/7039918#7039918) for an example.